# Why is my Auto-Clicker script getting this Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm new to JavaScript and I am trying to make an auto-clicker script. The problem is when I execute the script in the Developer Console, I get an error called "button.click is not a function" and the error just loops forever and the console. Here is my code:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default");
setInterval(function(){
    button.click()  
},200)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array check this example:

```html
<button class="btn-default" onclick="console.log('clicked');"></button>
<script>
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-default")[0];
setInterval(function(){
    button.click()  
},1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. So your "button" could not have `click` property, it's an array. You need to take an element, for example the first element:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default")[0];
```

---

But I would say that if you have a button click handler logic and you want to run it by some timer, then the best way would be to extract that logic into a function (let's name it `onClick`) and run this function by timer instead of click event emulation:

```
var onClick = function () {
  console.log("click!");
  // your click hanlder logic
};

setInterval(onClick, 200);

button.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

This also means that you don't bind the handler with onclick attr (`<button onclick="onClick()">`), but with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and this is preferable way to provide events handling.

Comment: I tried doing this script and it didn't work:

var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-default")[0];
setInterval(function(){
    button.click()  
},200)

What I mean by "it didn't work" is that now when I click the button, it doesn't even click at all, as seen in the below GIF.

https://gyazo.com/fc9d144d61882701b98bb116bacb3463

Comment: @IcyJake I updated the answer to provide full solution for your situation.

Comment: @ - dhilt I am so confused on how to make that into an auto-clicker. I'm completely new with JavaScript. Could you help me a little more? Sorry if I'm being annoying or anything. :u

Comment: @IcyJake Ok, show your full code, post it on https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://plnkr.co or whatever

Comment: @ - dhilt My full code is literally the one that you just posted, lol. I don't know what to do with it to make it an auto-clicker. This is the site that I'm trying to make an auto-clicker for. http://www.mcrpg.com/kohi-click-test/

Comment: @IcyJake I see you already have `$scope.buttonClick` as a click handler. So you need to run it in interval via `setInterval($scope.buttonClick, 200)` in that `clickTestController`. Do not forget to stop it with `clearInterval()`.